# Use case for Higher-Order Components in React?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

The tutorial about `component composition` at the official react.js describes how to use composition to avoid inheritance and for the most part I see the advantage here.
But the website also mentions `we haven’t found any use cases where we would recommend creating component inheritance hierarchies`
src: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

But then we have a tutorial about HOC (Higher-Order Component) pattern
src: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html
Which suggests writing functions for generating composite components as a means to avoid duplicate logic.
*This pattern is also used in Relay for components that work with GraphQL.*

For someone coming from a C# / Java / PHP background their HOC use cases look like obvious examples of when to use inheritance. Which is what I previously did myself in React and find it to be very intuitive and more importantly *easy for debugging.*

I'm also struggling to understand the advantage of generator functions used in HOC over regular composite components, which take inner components via props.

So my question is: **Is there a use case for HOC in React which couldn't be as easily solved either by composition or inheritance instead?**

*Examples would be appreciated.*

*Update:* Found this article about `Inheritance Inversion` which suggests having your wrapper class inherit from your inner class and calling it's render() method.
I might be biased so I wont discard this idea right away, since it might have practical usage, but I will have to look more into it first.
If you have an idea of when this could beat regular composition or inheritance please leave a comment or perhaps an answer if you think you have a good case.

Answer (score 4):

For those who came from any **Object-oriented Language** like **Java** it is important to take into account that **Javascript** is a **prototype-based** language meaning that object properties and methods can be shared through generalized objects that have the ability to be cloned and extended. This is known as **prototypical inheritance** and differs from **class inheritance**. In Javascript, too much inheritance can lead to endless confusion, and endless pain when you try to debug such code and also affect performance, that is why if you read Facebook’s article

- https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html at the very bottom you will read:

> At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven’t found any use cases where we would recommend creating
> component inheritance hierarchies

Said this, we should not mix the concept of two different patterns like **HOC** and **Composition**. They have different use cases.

---

A **higher-order component (HOC)** is an advanced technique in React for reusing component logic. By reading at the example on:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

it could seem a pattern used like obvious examples of when to use inheritance but it is not. Logic involved in a HOC is not only that.

**Some Examples**

- React-Redux uses a HOC called **connect** to map store state to props
- React-Router’s **withRouter** HOC provides route context to components needing access to history APIs

---

> Is there a use case for HOC in React which couldn't be as easily
> solved either by composition or inheritance instead?

I would say to always avoid inheritance and based on your needs to go for either **Composition** or **HOC** by taking into account that if you go for **Composition** you have at least to try following common rules like:

- Divide components into stateful “Composed” and stateless “Components”.
- If two components need access to the same state, move the state into their common parent. https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

An Example:

```js
class Composed extends React.Component {
      state = { 
         value: 'foo'
      }
      changeValue = value => this.setState({value})
      render() {
            <div>
              <Component1 value={this.state.value} changeValue={this.changeValue} />
              <Component2 value={this.state.value} />
            <div>
      }
}
```

---

Hope to have helped.